# How to initialized Pointer of Vector c++?

Tags: c++, vector, operator-overloading

The following code is not working :

```
vector< vector<int> > *te = new vector<  vector<int> >();     
(*te)[0].push_back(10);      
cout << (*te)[0][0];
```

How should I initialize it ?

Comment: Are you sure you need to dynamically allocate the vector?

Comment: How to write unmaintainable code...

Comment: yes  Juanchopanza...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not see a sense in dynamic allocation of the vector nevertheless a correct syntax can look like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > *pv = new std::vector<std::vector<int> >;

    pv->push_back( std::vector<int>( 1, 10 ) );

    std::cout << ( *pv )[0][0] << std::endl;

    delete pv;
}
```

The output is

```
10
```

Answer (score 0):

> `std::vector<std::vector<int>>* te = new std::vector<std::vector<int>>();`

This line isn't you're problem. However, it does beg the question **"Why are you dynamically allocating a `std::vector`?"**

> `(*te)[0].push_back(10);`

This line is your problem. You're accessing the 0<sup>th</sup> index of `te` but it's empty (i.e., **doing this invokes undefined behavior**). You need to add something to it first: `te->push_back(std::vector<int>());`.

#### Example Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>>* te = new std::vector<std::vector<int>>();

    // Add an empty `vector` to `te`
    te->push_back(std::vector<int>());

    // Add `10` to the first `vector` in `te` and print it
    (*te)[0].push_back(10);
    std::cout << (*te)[0][0];

    delete te;

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:** You should also be in the habit of using smart pointers and not worry about manually newing and deleting the memory (e.g., `std::unique_ptr` pointer and `std::make_unique`).